# How do I add two specific values to a database from a controller?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core-mvc

In the code below I'am trying to get the current logged in user's username and the details of the item they are ordering into the database, but it is not working because I simply do not know to add both the username and chosen item to the database.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder([Bind("Id,Name,Location,Price,Description")] Order order)
        { 
            var user = _userManager.GetUserName(User);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(order + user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

Any help with how I can implement this feature would be greatly appreciated. 
(Below is more code from my project)

> My entire PackagesController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using JTMajorProject.DataAccess.Models;
using JTMajorProject.Models;
using JTMajorProject.DataAccess;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace JTMajorProject.Controllers
{
    //[Route("/packages")]
    public class PackagesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly JTMajorProjectContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public PackagesController(JTMajorProjectContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }


        // GET: Packages
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString, string searchLocation)
        {

            var packages = from p in _context.Package
                         select p;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                packages = packages.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocation))
            {
                packages = packages.Where(s => s.Location.Contains(searchLocation));
            } 

            return View(await packages.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Packages/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {   
                return NotFound(); 
            } 

            var package = await _context.Package
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (package == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(package);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Order(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var package = await _context.Package
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (package == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(package);
        }

        // GET: Packages/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Packages/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598. 
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Location,Price,Description")] Package package)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(package);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(package);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder([Bind("Id,Name,Location,Price,Description")] Order order)
        { 
            var user = _userManager.GetUserName(User);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(order + user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(order);
        }

        // GET: Packages/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var package = await _context.Package.FindAsync(id);
            if (package == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(package);
        }

        // POST: Packages/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Location,Price,Description")] Package package)
        {
            if (id != package.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(package);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PackageExists(package.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(package);
        }

        // GET: Packages/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var package = await _context.Package
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (package == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(package);
        }

        // POST: Packages/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var package = await _context.Package.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Package.Remove(package);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool PackageExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Package.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

> Razor page for the ordering process which has a form to send data to the controller

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@using System.Security.Claims

@model JTMajorProject.DataAccess.Models.Package

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Order";
}

<div>
    <section style="background-color: black; height: 150px; width: 1520px"></section>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddOrder"> 
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <h1 style="margin-top:50px">Your Order: </h1>

            <div style="margin: 20px;">
                <h4>
                    Account - @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                    {
                        <a id="manage" class="text-black" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage" style="color: black">
                            @UserManager.GetUserName(User)
                        </a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a style="margin:20px">Currently not signed in.</a>
                    }
                </h4>
            </div>


            <div style="margin: 30px">
                <h4 style="margin-top: 50px;">Package</h4>
                <hr />
                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
            @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                <div style="margin: 30px">
                    <button type="submit">Confirm Order</button>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <a style="margin:30px; font-weight:bold; font-size: 25px;">Please sign in to purchase this order.</a>
            }

    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div style="margin: 30px">
                <a asp-action="Index">Back to Package List</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hl5d1VY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to make a one to many relation between your `IdentityUser` table and your `Order` table. For this you need to add a foreign key when deffining the `Order` model.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //This sets the relation
    public string IdentityUserId {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdentityUserId ")]
    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
}
```

More information on Relationships in ASP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Once you set up the relationship you should be able to add Orders to your table with a FK that links the Order to the user that made the Order. Your controller should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder([Bind("Id,Name,Location,Price,Description")] Order order)
{ 
    //Gets the ID of the currently logged user
    string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newOrder = New Order
        {
            Id = order.Id,
            Name = order.Name,
            Location = order.Location,
            Price = order.Price,
            Description = order.Description,

            //Here you make the relation between the order and the user that made it
            IdentityUserId = userId
        }

        _context.Add(newOrder);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(order);
}
```